# By which I can replace the use of ATL to have an equal or a better performance?

Tags: c++, .net, com, atl

I'm new to ATL developement. Refering to some links in the Net, COM is outdated by .NET.

Is there any technologie that replaces ATL?

ATL is basicaly used to build fast and small apps. Does .NET build smaller and faster apps?

What's the difference between building raw C++ .EXE apps and ATL .EXE apps, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ATL is just a framework / library on top of C++.  At the end of the day there is no fundamental difference between a plain old C++ app and an ATL one.  An ATL *tends* to associate with COM programming but that is not a necessity.

.Net on the other hand is a completely separate runtime.  It compiles down to IL and runs in a virtual machine (the CLR).

As to which is smaller or faster.  There are no hard truths here but in *general*

- C++ EXE / DLL tend to be smaller for equivalent size apps
- C++ startup time tends to be faster than .Net because it doesn't need a JIT
- .Net apps tend to have less issues around memory management, leaks and corrutpion as copmared to C++
- Languages targeting .Net tend to be easier to learn than C++

Comment: if I summarize even, the most difficult to develop C++ is the departure, after it becomes more powerful than .NET for advanced apps. What about my last posted question? And, If I build ATL projects non-based on COM technologie does will this sacrifice the purpose to which ATL was designed for (fast and small apps)?

Comment: @Siro in general .Net and C++ are equally powerful. There are some corner cases but they're pretty esoteric.  

I have used ATL in the past for non-COM apps, collections in particular are nice if STL isn't an option.  It's still very useful for that

Comment: Then, why does that COM is outdated by .NET? COM is way of C++ programming based on interfaces. What's is the difference between programming EXE apps with ATL and with raw C++, please? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @Siro COM is not outdated, it's very much alive and kicking (and will be for probably as long as Windows is).  COM at its core is just a way to define data contracts.  In C++ it does this with interfaces and simple marhallable types.  .Net is an entirely different environment to program against (can use COM though)

Comment: this was too long sorry @JaredPar, last question : What's is the difference between programming EXE apps with ATL and with raw C++?

Comment: @Siro you can create apps in ATL where the EXE is tied to executing a COM server.  This is somewhat difference than a typical C++ app and generally takes over the entry points to the application.  This is not a requirement though, ATL can and often is just used as a library

Comment: I would also add that .NET has a *huge* collection of out-of-the-box base classes - well it's a framework. I recently went back to native C++ after 10 years of C#, and I really miss all those classes.